# How to create modal class for give Json

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am using JPA as ORM in spring boot, I need to create modal class in spring boot. How to create it?

```
{
   "createdBy":2,
   "hospitalId":33,
   "doctorId":45,
   "advanceBookingDays":5,
   "dutyDetails":[
      {
         "tokenLimit":66,
         "date":"2010-4-6",
         "timeSlot":[
            {
               "startTime":"7:23:00",
               "endTime":"8:22:00"
            },
            {
               "startTime":"9:00:40",
               "endTime":"10:33:56"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "tokenLimit":32,
         "date":"2010-4-6",
         "advanceBookingDays":5,
         "timeSlot":[
            {
               "startTime":"7:23:00",
               "endTime":"8:22:00"
            },
            {
               "startTime":"9:00:40",
               "endTime":"10:33:56"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

How to create modal class

Comment: Do you mean you want to convert this json to your entity class?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create a model that will be a JPA entity, you can check the guide to Spring Data JPA : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/#initial

(Define a Simple Entity paragraph)

Keep in mind that JPA is the Java Persistence API and you'll use an implementation of it trough hibernate per example. You can talk about pure JPA if only use methods defined in the API.

Answer (score -1):

This tool may help you.

[www.jsonschema2pojo.org](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo

[image]

generated code like this:

```java
public class DutyDetail {

public Integer tokenLimit;
public String date;
public List<TimeSlot> timeSlot = null;
public Integer advanceBookingDays;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.Example.java---------------------

package com.example;

import java.util.List;

public class Example {

public Integer createdBy;
public Integer hospitalId;
public Integer doctorId;
public Integer advanceBookingDays;
public List<DutyDetail> dutyDetails = null;

}
-----------------------------------com.example.TimeSlot.java--------------------

package com.example;


public class TimeSlot {

public String startTime;
public String endTime;

}
```